# How do you find the point where two writers of text meet?

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, natural-language

It is said that I have a text that I am familiar with, with author X writing the beginning and author Y writing the end. I'm not sure where the line between the authors should be drawn. The text is divided into chapters/paragraphs based on the topics covered. Because there is no plot, the themes change from chapter to chapter, but I believe there is some stylistic/verbal/subconscious line that changes at some critical point throughout the text so that the points that are most likely to be transition points can be identified.

What do you think should be done to arrive at this conclusion?

Comment: Have you been able to detect stylistic differences between the two authors (say by comparing the first and last chapters)? You will have to avoid words that are linked to subject matter and depend on such things as usages of _the_ (frequencies of "the" beginning sentence of clause, and "of the," "in the," "on the," "for the,  "to the" and so on. More obviously, if one author is North American and the other  Is British, there should be many obvious differences in spelling (-ise/-ize, -er/-re) word choice "while/whilst", use of verb tenses, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that one wrote the beginning and the other wrote the end, you can annotate each sentence in the first paragraph as author A and the rest as author B. Train a supervised machine learning model or several (e.g. an ensemble of SVM, NB, LR, RF) on this annotation, cross-validate and note the accuracy of the model. Since words indicative of topics might mess up the model, you better focus on stop words, adjectives, and sentence lengths.

Then reset the border to annotate the first two paragraphs to A and repeat. Note the accuracy. Then annotate the first three as A and repeat. Do this until you reach the situation where all is A, except for the last paragraph.

If there were two authors and there is a difference in writing, there will be a point where the model is most accurate.